Tag alias: PKE -> Public-key
A couple of times I've tried to tag something as pke, but the chosen tag is public-key. I think this is a very common acronym for public key cryptography, and do not think it would lead to confusion or ambiguity.
I don't have enough reputation to suggest this as an alias on the site, so I was wondering if people here agreed?

Thank you for the suggestion. I created the tag synonym.
